# Calculate Hours Worked Per Week

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I'm currently using two lists, one stores tasks **[Task List]**, the other stores the hours worked for completed tasks **[Time Sheet List]**

When a user marks a task as complete, it creates a corresponding Time sheet entry in the Time Sheet list.

**I'm currently trying to group time sheet entries so that I can calculate the total hours an employee has worked that week.**

I've tried creating a calculated column that assigns the week number based on the date, then group by that week number but the syntax is proving difficult.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some further info: The field i'm using is the Start Date, the year starts November 1st. So the current calculation should return week 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax will get the week number based on the created column, you'd need to modify the column with your own. (This is based on European week numbers instead of American)

```
=INT(([created]-DATE(YEAR([created]-WEEKDAY([created]-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([created]-WEEKDAY([created]-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)
```

This blog gives a good break down of how the syntax is created (quote below to preserve in case the blog goes down:

https://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/use-the-calculated-field-to-show-weeknumber-in-sharepoint-2010/

> Calculate the distance between the beginning of the year (with regard of the start of week 1) to the datecolumn
>
> Add the day of the week of the 1st January of the datecolumn year added with 5 (Thursday)
>
> Divide by number of days in a week (usually 7
>
> Floor by doing a cast to INT

Comment: The syntax doesn't seem to work, unsure as to why. I've replaced the column name with my column name so there shouldn't be any issues. This solution is for SP2010 so it could be outdated. My Syntax: =INT(([Start Date]-DATE(YEAR([Start Date]-WEEKDAY([Start Date]-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([Start Date]-WEEKDAY(Start Date-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)

Comment: Your last start date doesn't have [] around it, could you update to [Start Date] and try again please?

Comment: Apologies, that has sorted it out! I had just copied the snippet you had posted, it had brackets missing on it to. Final point, this is based on January being the first week of the year, how do i set it to make November start as the first week?

Comment: Whoops, I'll update the original post with the updated brackets. I've done a quick test, and to update it to use November you should just need to update the bits which say "1,3" to say "11,1" (Please note, I've not had a chance to test it fully so I'd recommend trying with a few different dates to make sure you get expected results)

Comment: Qurator, absolutely spot. Rigourously tested the calculation, works perfectly. Much obliged.

Comment: Sadly the formula has broken since the new year has begun. It now shows my current week as being -42.

Comment: Can you try the following please? (I think the issue is regarding the year switch over so I've added a if statement for Nov & Dev) (It's showing today as Week 11 for me and Dec 6 as Week 6)

`=IF(MONTH([Created])>=11, 
INT(([created]-DATE(YEAR([created]),11,1)+
(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([created]),11,1)),"d")))/7)+1,
INT(([created]-DATE(YEAR([created])-1,11,1)+
(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([created]),11,1)),"d")))/7)+1)`

Comment: Spot on once again @Qurator . Found another way to do it as well which is: =INT(([Actual Start]-DATE(2017,11,1)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([Actual Start]-WEEKDAY([Actual Start]-1)+4),11,1))+5)/7)